# ASCII encoding error when sending an email in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, smtplib

I have a program in Python3 which sends mails. It works perfectly on several computers, but there is one in which not. I tried and this one only works when there are not any special characters like 'ñ' or 'á', 'é', etc...

I got the next error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\whatever' in position x: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And this is my code:

```
html = '<h1>niñería</h1>'
text = 'niñería'

mail = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
mail['From'] = 'my_account@gmail.com'
mail['To'] = 'destiny@gmail.com'
mail['Cc'] = ''
mail['Subject'] = 'My subject'

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container. According to RFC 2046, the last
# part of a multipart message, in this case the HTML message, is best
# and preferred.
mail.attach(part1)
mail.attach(part2)

msg_full = mail.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login('my_account@gmail.com', 'my_password')
server.sendmail('my_account@gmail.com', ['destiny@gmail.com'], msg_full)
server.quit()
```

Is there any magic line like `.encode('utf-8')` or `.decode('utf-8')` which could make my email content recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved. I only had to change the line:

```
msg_full = mail.as_string()
```

And write instead:

```
msg_full = mail.as_string().encode()
```